Building an App for users to create SPL Tokens & Set Authority
I've built a few launchpads before, but only on EVM for ETH/BSC, and keep getting stuck while building with Solana/SVM.
I'm building a platform for users to create SPL tokens by inputting token details like:  Token name, Token symbol, Decimals, Description, and Upload Image.
Along with basic information I'd like to add optional toggles to add additional info such as:  Social Links, Immutable, Revoke Freeze, Revoke Mint.
 (The Revoke Freeze/Mint could be a toggle enable/disable or just another step to do after creation)
The concept is similar to these 3 platforms: 
https://www.solauncher.org/create/spl 
https://www.snapdeploy.io/ 
https://www.soltokencreator.io/
While researching it seems the common method is using Metaplex, Umi, MPL Token Metadata, and similar.  But I can't figure out how to structure it to allow other users to create on their own and add the additional functions.
My question is, are there are useful resources or existing structures to use as an example for something similar to this?  I've found code for creating basic SPL Tokens, but can't find much info on how to add more options.
I'm still pretty new to Solana and any help would be amazing.

If you are doing this on a frontend side, use the connected wallet to create an instance of UMI and the tokens minted from it will have the authorities(mint, freeze and update if enabled), set to umi.identity
// --- snip imports ---

const wallet = useAnchorWallet();

const umi = createUmi("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
  .use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet))
  .use(mplTokenMetadata());

async function createAndMintFungible() {
    const mint = generateSigner(umi);

    // mint token
    let umiTX = await createAndMint(umi, {
        mint,
        name: "",
        symbol: "",
        uri: "",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0),
        decimals: ,
        amount: 1_000_000,
        tokenOwner: umi.identity.publicKey,
        isMutable: false,
        tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
    }).buildWithLatestBlockhash(umi);

    // sign with the mint address and provider
    let signedTX = await signTransaction(umiTX, [mint, umi.identity]);

    //convert to web3 js TX
    const web3TX = toWeb3JsTransaction(signedTX);
    let txHash = await conn.sendTransaction(web3TX);
    console.log(txHash);
}

check out the guides for a more detailed breakdown https://developers.metaplex.com/guides/javascript/how-to-create-an-spl-token-on-solana
